# Display block label cannot contain text

Tags: html, css

I am creating collection of pictures for testing. There is label of frame which contains picture and another label which contains text and has background color of yellow with half opacity to be visible.

Unfortunately, Yellow colored label cannot contain text. I do believe this issue was caused because of `display: block` style.

Since yellow colored label cannot contain text, overflow-x is created and text is moved right next to the label:

[image]

HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="inv_display" style="height: 500px; display: block;">
                <ul class="inv_form" style="list-style-type:none;overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <li><label style="color: white;font-family: 'Lato';font-size: 1.5em;display: block;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px;">Pics</label></li>
                    <li><div style="width: 100%;height:355px;">
                        <div style="position:absolute;overflow-y: scroll;">
                            <ul class="item_menu" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 15px; list-style-type: none; overflow-y: scroll; display: block;">

                                <li><label id="l_Ovk3rmwF3xR" class="inv_items" style="width:120px;height:120px;background-color:#1d1e1e;cursor: pointer;float:left;margin-right:15px;text-align: center;padding-top: 0;user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;moz-user-select: none;"><img style="width: 90%;height: 85%;display: inline-block;margin-top: 10%;user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;moz-user-select: none;" src="http://i.imgur.com/bpYwZ7q.jpg"></label><label style="position: relative;width: 120px;display: block;height: 120px;background-color: rgba(244, 176, 66, 0.5);color: white;">Panda</label></li>

                                <li><label id="l_0vk3rmwF3xG" class="inv_items" style="width:120px;height:120px;background-color:#1d1e1e;cursor: pointer;float:left;margin-right:15px;text-align: center;padding-top: 0;user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;moz-user-select: none;"><img style="width: 90%;height: 85%;display: inline-block;margin-top: 10%;user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;moz-user-select: none;" src="http://i.imgur.com/GuAuaa7.jpg"></label><label style="position: relative;width: 120px;display: block;height: 120px;background-color: rgba(244, 176, 66, 0.5);color: white;">Tiger</label></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

<style>
    .inv_display {
      min-width: 600px;
      position: relative;
      left: 5%;
      background-color: black;
      border: 1px solid white;
    }
    .inv_form {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0;
        overflow-x:auto;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .inv_form li {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

Please see [Fiddle with full code](https://jsfiddle.net/q2k2um9k/2/) & [Embedded result](https://jsfiddle.net/q2k2um9k/2/embedded/result).

So again, The text should be inside the yellow label overlay, but instead it gets moved next to it.

What could the problem be? Is there any way to fit text node into display block label? If not, is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] *in the question itself*, **not only on a third-party site**.

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/q2k2um9k/3/

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, but the yellow background label must overlay the the other label. Like it is on embedded result.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Fixed, Added all the relevant code.

Comment: _Label much?_ ... seriously, what are all those labels supposed to be good for? No `for` attributes, no form elements inside - so, _why_ labels? Sure you not rather want to use `figure` maybe?

Comment: @CBroe I need to bind them with checkbox input's later, so that's the only reason i use them atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use absolute positioning to position the second label over the first.

```css
.inv_display {
  min-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.inv_form {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}

.inv_form li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/* new css */

.item_menu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.item_menu label {
  display: block;
}

.item_menu li label:last-child {
  background-color: rgba(244, 176, 66, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="inv_display" style="height: 500px; display: block;">
  <ul class="inv_form" style="list-style-type:none;overflow-y: scroll;">
    <li>
      <label style="color: white;font-family: 'Lato';font-size: 1.5em;display: block;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px;">Pics</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="width: 100%;height:355px;">
        <div style="position:absolute;overflow-y: scroll;">
          <ul class="item_menu" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 15px; list-style-type: none; overflow-y: scroll; display: block;">

            <li>
              <label id="l_Ovk3rmwF3xR" class="inv_items" style="width:120px;height:120px;background-color:#1d1e1e;cursor: pointer;text-align: center;padding-top: 0;user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;moz-user-select: none;"><img style="width: 90%;height: 85%;display: inline-block;margin-top: 10%;user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;moz-user-select: none;" src="http://i.imgur.com/bpYwZ7q.jpg"></label>
              <label style="color: white;">Panda panda panda panda panda</label>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label id="l_0vk3rmwF3xG" class="inv_items" style="width:120px;height:120px;background-color:#1d1e1e;cursor: pointer;text-align: center;padding-top: 0;user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;moz-user-select: none;"><img style="width: 90%;height: 85%;display: inline-block;margin-top: 10%;user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;moz-user-select: none;" src="http://i.imgur.com/GuAuaa7.jpg"></label>
              <label style="color: white;">Tiger tiger tiger tiger</label>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot for the answer, but main problem still stays the same. The text nodes - "Panda" and "Tiger" should be inside their yellow colored labels instead of being at the side, could that be possible if the yellow colored label has display block?

Comment: @ShellRox oh you want the overlay and the text on top of the image?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason text node cannot get into overlay.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also would it be possible to wrap the text? `word-wrap: break-word` doesn't seem to work, I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: @ShellRox updated. you have `.inv_form { white-space: nowrap; }` causing that.